# Vim -- drawing errors, strange artifacts, and improper sizing

Tags: vim

When I use vim in bash with the standard MacOS terminal I get this whacky artifact behavior, especially with JSON files. The wrong line numbers will show, and the wrong lines will show. When I move the cursor around, it will 'uncover' the actual characters in those positions, and result in a crazy mess of curly brackets or line numbers (in the case of a JSON file).

[image: artifacting behavior]

When I run vim in bash with iTerm2, the vim window only takes up a set amount of space, which is often less than half the area of the entire terminal window.

[image]

Perhaps there's some issue with my .vimrc file?

```
" -----  Native Vim Configuration -----
let g:netrw_altv=1
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
"autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.json set ft=javascript
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

set number

" ----- Vim Plugin Manager -----
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
  \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
    Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
    Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
    Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
    Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
    Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 
      \ 'do': 'npm install',
      \ 'for': ['javascript', 'css', 'scss', 'json'] }
    Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic',
    Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx',
    Plug 'tpope/vim-surround',
    Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
call plug#end()

" ----- Vim Plugin Configuration -----
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

if executable('ag')
    " Use Ag over Grep
    set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

    " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files, does respect .gitignore
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'
endif

 colorscheme gruvbox

 let g:gruvbox_termcolors = '256'
 let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'medium'
 let g:gruvbox_contrast_light = 'soft'

 set background=dark
```

Other potential factors: I am using ssh to connect to a pretty beat-up server.

The graphics card on my machine seems to be somewhat flawed. Periodically my display will flash black and I see polygonal glitches when I am using the graphics card.

Comment: For the first problem, the hack I use is to just run `:redraw` and it fixes the problem. I map it to `:rd`. For me, running redraw can fix things, and then when I put vim in the background and return, I sometimes need to redraw again.